# How can I connect from one website to database of another website in php

Tags: php, database-connection

How can I connect from one website to database of another website in php.

Comment: Is there a good reason for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other website will require their port to be open for yours to connect to. They will also need the database user to allow connections that are not just from the local machine.

If you have a fairly standard LAMP set-up, this will mean opening port 3306 on the database server so outside connections can be made, and a database user setting up that will be able to connect from the outside world.

Bear in mind their may be latency issues.

Comment: I want to use the database inside another server....I have given mysql_connect("<remote site ip>","username","password") and mysql_connect("<remote site domain>","username","password")....but both do not work.....can you tell me what more I can do.....I have the ftp details of both the sites....

Comment: Most setups would not allow non-local database connections out of the box. Allowing such connections over something as insecure as the internet is something that should not be undertaken lightly.

Answer (score 0):

You add the connection details in `config.php` or where you store them, and `another-website.com` or the IP to the host url (You probably have `localhost` there), then the username and the password.